# NoReverseMatch in render_to_response with django-social-auth

Tags: django, python-2.7

I would like to make just a page that has link to login to twitter/facebook/google with django-social-auth.

but I get a error `NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '' with arguments '(u'twitter',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

```
  def index(request):
        ctx = {}
        return render_to_response('index_before_login.html', {}, RequestContext(request))
```

index_before_login.html is following

```
<li><a href="{% url socialauth_begin 'twitter' %}">Enter using Twitter</a></li>
```

urls.py is following

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', 'lebabcartoon.views.index'),
        #url(r'^socialauth_', 'lebabcartoon.views.index'),
        url('', include('social_auth.urls')),
```

my environment is
Django ver1.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
django-social-auth: 0.7.5

anyideas?

Comment: 1) There is no Django version 1.5 yet. 2)https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap url name in quotes

```
{% url 'socialauth_begin' 'twitter' %}
```

Comment: I did so right now, oh my gods. it worked !! thank you! oh my gods. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To save someone using the new python-social-auth and django > 1.4

Use this :

```
{% url 'social:begin' 'twitter' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, try adding the following to the url.py file in your project.

```
url(r'auth/', include('social_auth.urls'))
```

And also make sure your url parameters are wrapped in quotes like so.

```
{% url "socialauth_begin" "twitter" %}
```